# In Polars, how do you multiply a column of floats with a column of lists?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Given an example dataframe where we have column 'b' containing lists, and each list has the same length (so it also could be converted to arrays)

```py
df_test = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1., 2., 3.], 'b': [[2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4]]})
df_test
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b         │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ f64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ [2, 2, 2] │
│ 2.0 ┆ [3, 3, 3] │
│ 3.0 ┆ [4, 4, 4] │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

How do I end up with

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬───────────┬────────────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b         ┆ new                │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---                │
│ f64 ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[f64]          │
╞═════╪═══════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ [2, 2, 2] ┆ [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]    │
│ 2.0 ┆ [3, 3, 3] ┆ [6.0, 6.0, 6.0]    │
│ 3.0 ┆ [4, 4, 4] ┆ [12.0, 12.0, 12.0] │
└─────┴───────────┴────────────────────┘
```

without using `map_rows`?

The best way I could think of was to use `map_rows`, which is like `apply` in pandas. Not really the most efficient thing according to docs but it works:

```py
df_temp = df_test.map_rows(lambda x: ([x[0] * i for i in x[1]],))
df_temp.columns = ['new']
df_test = df_test.hstack(df_temp)
```

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, polars [doesn't support](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7210) referencing named columns within [`pl.Expr.list.eval`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.eval.html). Otherwise, that would've been the go-to solution.

I think, the solution by @ouroboros1 is already on the right track by exploding the column, performing the operation, and imploding again. However, it can be simplified quite a bit as follows.

```py
(
    df_test
    .with_columns(
        (
            pl.col("b").explode() * pl.col("a")
        )
        .implode().over(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
        .alias("new")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬───────────┬────────────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b         ┆ new                │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---                │
│ f64 ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[f64]          │
╞═════╪═══════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ [2, 2, 2] ┆ [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]    │
│ 2.0 ┆ [3, 3, 3] ┆ [6.0, 6.0, 6.0]    │
│ 3.0 ┆ [4, 4, 4] ┆ [12.0, 12.0, 12.0] │
└─────┴───────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Especially, we can avoid explicitly creating and dropping the index column as well as the `pl.DataFrame.group_by().agg()` construct, which would become more tedious to handle if the DataFrame had more columns.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about `implode.over`. That's really convenient. Only adding that `new=(pl.col("b").explode() * pl.col("a"))` gets the column added as 'new', rather than overwriting existing 'b'.

Comment: @ouroboros1 Good catch! I've edited the answer to include an alias.

Comment: If `a` is all unique values then you can just `over('a')` instead of making an implicit index. If there are duplicates in `a` then it'll panic.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit*: adjusted answer to make sure that it works with duplicate values in column 'a'.

---

Here's one approach:

**Data**

N.B. Below changing 'a' from `[1., 2., 3.]` to `[1., 1., 3.]` to exemplify the need for an extra temporary column 'idx' for the groupby.

```py
import polars as pl

# changing 'a' from `[1., 2., 3.]` to `[1., 1., 3.]` to exemplify need temp `idx`
df_test = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1., 1., 3.], 
                        'b': [[2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4]]})
df_test

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b         │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ f64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ [2, 2, 2] │
│ 1.0 ┆ [3, 3, 3] │
│ 3.0 ┆ [4, 4, 4] │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

**Code**

```py
df_new = (
    df_test.with_columns(idx=pl.arange(0, pl.len()))
           .explode('b')
           .with_columns(new=(pl.col('a') * pl.col('b')))
           .group_by(['idx', 'a'], maintain_order=True)
           .agg(pl.col("b"), pl.col("new"))
           .drop('idx')
)

df_new

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬───────────┬────────────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b         ┆ new                │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---                │
│ f64 ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[f64]          │
╞═════╪═══════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ [2, 2, 2] ┆ [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]    │
│ 1.0 ┆ [3, 3, 3] ┆ [3.0, 3.0, 3.0]    │
│ 3.0 ┆ [4, 4, 4] ┆ [12.0, 12.0, 12.0] │
└─────┴───────────┴────────────────────┘
```

**Explanation**

- First, create a column 'idx' (using [`pl.DataFrame.with_columns`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_columns.html),  [`pl.arange`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.arange.html), and [`pl.len`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.len.html)) to keep track of each row. I.e., we use this column to differentiate between rows that have the *same* value in 'a'.
- Now, use [`pd.DataFrame.explode`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html) to get the list values for 'b' into separate rows.
- Next, chain `pl.DataFrame.with_columns` to multiply column 'a' by column 'b', assigning the result to 'new'.
- Finally, we want to get back the lists: use [`pl.DataFrame.group_by`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by.html) on columns 'idx' and 'a', adding `maintain_order=True` to keep the data in the correct order, and apply [`groupby.agg`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.dataframe.group_by.GroupBy.agg.html) on columns 'b' and 'new'.
- Clean up by dropping 'idx' (using [`pl.DataFrame.drop`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.drop.html)).

Comment: Thank you! Works wonders and I learned a new strategy!

Comment: @Horace: you're welcome. I've updated the answer. While the original version did work on your `df_test`, it would actually 'regroup' the rows incorrectly if column 'a' has duplicate values. Corrected version takes this possibility into account.